# Unable to build fsharp projects using FAKE. Getting "Cannot open assembly'.paket/paket.bootstrapper.exe': No such file or directory." Error

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, f#-fake, ionide

Created a new fsharp project from Visual Studio Code (Version 1.12.2) while trying to build it with FAKE it is showing this error
"Cannot open assembly '.paket/paket.bootstrapper.exe': No such file or directory."

I checked the .paket folder of my project the paket.bootstrapper.exe is missing in there.
I using ionide 2.25.14, ionide-fake 1.2.3 and ionide-Paket 1.6.3.

I tried building the project with msbuild and it is building without any errors.

### **EDIT**

This is how the build target is defined in the build.fsx.

```
Target "Build" (fun _ -> 
    // compile all projects below src/app/ 
    MSBuildDebug buildDir "Build"
    appReferences |> Log "AppBuild-Output: " 
)
```

Downloading paket.bootstrapper.exe from github and adding in to the .packet folder resolved the issue.

Comment: probably you have fake build script that is calling paket to restore the packages. Check the `build.fsx` file. You could just install [paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/) or copy the .exe from another project. Usually if you bootstrap a project in ionide it will create the .paket folder and put the exe in there though.

Comment: This is how the build target is defined in the build.fsx.
Target "Build" (fun _ ->
    // compile all projects below src/app/
    MSBuildDebug buildDir "Build" appReferences
    |> Log "AppBuild-Output: "
)

Downloading paket.bootstrapper.exe from github and adding in to the .packet folder resolved the error. 
Thanks.
So do I need to copy this exe to every f# project I create ?

Comment: You can edit  your own question with additional info, it's probably easier to read, especially for code. 1. You can put the bootstrapper and paket exe onto the path. 2. You don't have to use paket for  any project (although it's a good idea).

Comment: Point to note here, Paket recommend you check in the .`\paket\paket.bootstrapper.exe` file to your repository: https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, and maybe the best thing to do is to download `paket.bootstrapper.exe` if it didn't get generated along with your project.

Your build script is trying to run `paket.bootstrapper.exe`, but can't find it, likely because your project was generated without one.  If you already have a folder named `.paket`, then your project was likely generated with a `paket.exe`, instead.

The only thing `paket.bootstrapper.exe` does is download the latest version of `paket.exe`.  Your build script is just trying to automate keeping your package manager up to date.